# My React app shows a blank page at one of the stages on iPhone. Anywhere else (even Safari on MacOS), it works as intended

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, iphone, safari

I am working on an application where users need to fill in some personal information to register an appointment. (Can't share too many details as it is confidential work)

At some point, my application opens a "popup" type of component which simply lists the previously filled information for the user. It acts as an overview step before proceeding to the next steps of registration.

I tried this on various browsers. On Pc, it works on Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. On Android, I only tested Chrome, and it worked fine there. On MacOS, I tested Chrome and Safari, and it was fine on both.

But when I tried it on an iPhone, I just get a blank page when I get to this aforementioned step.
I am confused as to what the problem might be, because everywhere else, it seems to work fine. Even on the Apple ecosystem itself, there are devices which render the application correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

On the device, enable Web Inspector in Safari's settings. Then on a Mac, open Safari, enable the Develop menu if you haven't already and use it to attach to the Web Inspector on the device (there will be a submenu named for the device, with all inspectable frames as menu items). Now you have a full inspector to investigate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was not aware Safari had this feature on iPhone. I will investigate the problem and post back with a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pinpoint the problem to a date field. For some reason, Safari on iOS could not parse a string timestamp to a specific date (It was throwing an error when I was creating a new Date object and passing in the timestamp to the constructor).

I formatted the date to a string manually and everything is working fine now.

Comment: That sounds like it makes sense. There are only two options that work well for this: use the Date constructor and walk a very narrow path to only use strings that all browsers accept and treat the exact same, or use a parsing library.